# SQL Server Применить 2 раза SELECT к одной таблице

Tags: sql-server

Есть БД с одной таблицей `Contracts` с колонками `id`,  `client_id`, `type_id`, `dateFrom`, `dateTo`. Т.е. `контракты`, `клиент`, `тип договора`, `сроки действия договора`.

Надо вытащить строки, которые отвечают условиям:

1. заданного типа `сlient_id` и `type_id`
2. находятся в диапазоне `dataFrom` и `dataTo` хотя бы своей частью
3. не пересекаются по времени

По отдельности сделал:

**Запрос 1**
Вернёт строки, входящие в задаваемый диапазон дат

```
DECLARE @client INT, @contract_type INT, @date_start DATE, @date_stop DATE;
SET @client = SOME_NUMBER_1;
SET @contract_type = SOME_NUMBER_2;
SET @date_start = 'SOME_START_DATA';
SET @date_stop = 'SOME_FINISH_DATA';

SELECT * FROM Contracts
WHERE Contracts.Client_Id = @client AND Contracts.Type_Id = @contract_type 
AND DATEDIFF(day,Contracts.DateTo, @date_start) <= 0
AND DATEDIFF(day, Contracts.DateFrom, @date_stop) >= 0
order by Contracts.DateFrom;
```

Возвращает правильно

**Запрос 2**
Нужны строки, не перекрывающиеся с любой другой.

```
select
case when
  (C1.DateFrom between C2.DateFrom and C2.DateTo) or
  (C1.DateTo between C2.DateFrom and C2.DateTo) or
  (C2.DateFrom between C1.DateFrom and C1.DateTo) or
  (C2.DateTo between C1.DateFrom and C1.DateTo) or
  (C1.DateFrom < C2.DateFrom and C1.DateTo > C2.DateTo) or
  (C1.Datefrom > C2.DateFrom and C1.DateTo < C2.DateTo)
 then
  'yes'
 else
  'no'
 end as OverLapping
from Contracts AS C1, Contracts AS C2
WHERE  C1.Type_Id = SOME_NUMBER_2 AND C2.Type_Id = SOME_NUMBER_2
AND C1.Client_Id = SOME_NUMBER_1 AND C2.Client_Id = SOME_NUMBER_1
```

Не смог сделать лучше: возвращает одну колонку с 'yes''no', но вроде бы то что надо.

**Что не получается сделать**
К результату запроса 1 надо применить запрос 2.
Нужны полные строки, со значением 'no'.

Comment: *Надо вытащить строки, которые отвечают условиям* Вы понимаете, что в общем случае возможны несколько наборов записей, отвечающих указанным критериям? Пример: диапазоны 1-2, 3-5, 4-6, 7-8. Соответственно есть два варианта - либо 1-2, 3-5, 7-8, либо 1-2, 4-6, 7-8. Сформулируйте свои требования так, чтобы решение всегда было единственным.

Comment: Ну и читаем [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особенно пункты 5 и 3.